# Copy paste specific cell values from one work sheet to another based on a specific criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Its been a while since I have done any sort of coding, so I am very rusty.
I am trying to write some VBA code, so that when a button is clicked in the excel sheet it will check another sheet in the same workbook and copy of specific cell values.  This is based on a criteria in one of the columns (column 15, I counted); I should probably add that the data is in a table.  if that row meets the specified criteria from column 15, then specific columns are copied over to the worksheet with the button.

I do have some code, but I know there is a lot missing from it.

Would appreciate some input, am I on the right track?  can anyone help on there I can get more info and tips on the coding I need to use.  Not sure if there is an easy way to do this using tables?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

''This will count how many rows are populated in the table''
a = Worksheets("Billable").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

''Loop will run from row 6 to the last row (Row 6 is the first row in table)''
For i = 6 To a
    ''If statement which will check the status column for Detailed Estimate Submitted > column 15''
    If Worksheets("Billable").Cells(i, 15).Value = "Detailed Estimate Submitted" Then
      Worksheets("Billable").Rows(i).Copy
      Worksheets("PM_Forecast").Activate
      b = Worksheets("PM_Forecast").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      Worksheets("PM_Forecast").Cells(a + 1, 1).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

An example of the table: -
I only need to copy over 3 of the columns if they meet a specific criteria in the status column

[image: Table Headings]

Comment: Do you need copying the format/formula, too? Or only values? I am asking that in order to understand that the fastest method (using arrays) to copy can be used...

Comment: I think this can be achieved with formulas. If you can provide a sample of your sheets and expected results, it would help

Comment: I just need the values in the cells copied over to the worksheet when they meet a certain cireteria.  I need to run this once every couple of days so probably will need to clear the worksheet each time before the info is copied over.  Added an example of the table to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not answer my question regarding the format pasting...

So, please, test the next code which pastes on a classical way. But without selecting and declaring all used variables:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim shB As Worksheet, shPM As Worksheet, lastRowB As Long, lastRowPM As Long
 Dim i As Long, lastCol As Long

 Set shB = Worksheets("Billable")
 Set shPM = Worksheets("PM_Forecast")

 lastRowB = Worksheets("Billable").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

 'Loop will run from row 6 to the last row (Row 6 is the first row in table)''
 For i = 6 To lastRowB
    If shB.Cells(i, 15).Value = "Detailed Estimate Submitted" Then
        lastCol = shB.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastRowPM = shPM.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        shB.Range(shB.Range("A" & i), shB.Cells(i, lastCol)).Copy _
                                   shPM.Cells(lastRowPM + 1, 1)
    End If
 Next
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

For array using variant you must only declare a new variable `Dim arr As Variant` and replace this part:

```
shB.Range(shB.Range("A" & i), shB.Cells(i, lastCol)).Copy _
                                   shPM.Cells(lastRowPM + 1, 1)
```

with this one:

```
arr = shB.Range(shB.Range("A" & i), shB.Cells(i, lastCol)).Value
shPM.Cells(lastRowPM + 1, 1).Resize(, UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
```

Then, delete the code line `Application.CutCopyMode = False`. It is not necessary, anymore, since the Clipboard memory is not used...

And use `Option Explicit` on top of your module. It will save you many times, when the code will become complex.

Comment: Thanks, yes your code above works.  Is this a better way than what I had? Is using an array better?  Wasnt sure.  I just now need to work out how to only copy over specific cells from that row which meets the cireteria.

Comment: @user3088476: I would say, yes, it is... Declaring all variables helps VBA to consume less resources and stops you to make some mistakes. Then, selecting and activating only consumes Excel resources and do not bring any benefit. They only make the code bushy/longer and more difficult to debug in case of a problem. The array way works only in memory and it is very fast, due to that.  You can see the difference if you would have big size ranges to be handled. But it is good to make the habit to use them each time if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am going to see if I can work out the copying of specific columns only when the criteria is met

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment so I will ask the question through this answer:

Your variable b is currently not being used, I think it was meant to be in this line: `Worksheets("PM_Forecast").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select` but you have written a instead of b.

Does this solve your current issue?

Comment: Yes it did. I only want to copy over specific cells from the rows